# Port forwarding for Teamspeak server

Tags: router, lan, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward ports 9987, 10011 and 30033 for my Teamspeak 3 server. My setup for the connections is as follows:

- Bayantel modem-router (Aztech 5001en)
- D-LINK DIR 300 (wireless router) connected to Aztech router
- Computer is connected via Ethernet to  LAN port 1 on the D-LINK

The D-LINK is running in Access Point mode so that I the other wireless devices can connect to the internet.

I tried to set up prot forwarding on my D-LINK but the option is greyed out.

---

How can I set up port forwarding? Where do I set up port forwarding? Do I have to do it on my Aztech router or on my D-LINK?

Comment: Let me just verify one thing: You are trying to host a Teamspeak 3 **server** right?

Comment: yes I am. I have already installed the client and followed a "how to" on how to run a server which I did successfully create one. however My friend cannot connect to the server I made.

Comment: Could you please look up the IP addresses of both your computer and the Aztech modem router? It seems your D-LINK isn’t that active a component.

Comment: As you've turned the D-Link into a dummy switch (for simplicity's sake)(access point mode) it doesn't understand port forwarding. You do the port forwarding through your Aztech modem/router to the server's IP on your network. Don't forget to give the server a static IP outside your DHCP range or reserve it an address.

Comment: my computer's ip address is 192.168.1.111 (i set this one manually. before, it was 192.168.1.2. the aztech's ip (i think, please bear with me) is 192.168.1.1 (because that's how I access the settings)

Comment: The Aztech is bound to be .1.1 as it's the gateway. The D-Link is now a switch but it must be given an IP too. What is your DHCP pool size?

Comment: i think the d-link's ip is 192.168.1.3 as i can see that come up in the main page of the settings when i log in to the Aztech modem. is that the IP POOL COUNT? it says its 253.

Comment: this is what i did yesterday in the aztech modem as i was trying to figure it out. http://www.picamatic.com/view/10882049_pf/ when i use the portforward network utilities (the one with port checker) it says "Your port is not open or not reachable."

Answer (score 0):

Since your D-Link router is running in AP-mode, meaning that it just bridges everything from LAN to WLAN, you have to setup port forwarding in the bayantel router.